# Accessing SMB shares via Media Station X (on a Samsung Smart TV)

Tags: url, samba

I'm looking at setting up ([Media Station X](http://msx.benzac.de/info/?tab=Home)) to allow me to stream media directly from my NAS to my smart TV. Media Station X is basically a bunch of json files that the application grabs from a webserver to tell it how to draw menus and find media content. I've been trying to setup a simple trial on my home network to see if I can use this platform. I have a simple menu written, which works OK on the TV, but I'm having trouble with the video URL.

Below is the example from the API. Note the HTTP protocol. This works on my TV.

```
{
   "title": "Video 2",
   "playerLabel": "Video 2",
   "action": "video:http://msx.benzac.de/media/video2.mp4"
}
```

I replaced the action URL with the Samba path and user credentials as below, but I just get 'content not found'. I've tried using the IP address instead with the same error. I also tied without the credentials (never know...).

```
...
   "action": "video:smb://user:pass@hostname/path/to/file"
...
```

Am I missing something in the samba URL? Has anyone else managed to get this platform to server local files to their TV? If so, how did you achieve this?

Comment: I've been looking for info too on how to make it work, it has to do with a server side tec called CORDS, I host mine on a cloud bucket and have not gotten it to work just yet....will keep you posted if I get it right

Comment: Be interested in your results. I ended up spinning up a web server on the NAS to provide the content as per the working demo code above. Bit annoying though that you can't just point it to a LAN file address. Having wanted to use Samba I don't actually know if my TV has a Samba client installed.